# How to query by parent in ElasticSearch 6.5?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I know we use `has_child` to get **parent-child** structure data, but `has_parent` can't query by parent field.
I want to query by the parent so I must use `has_parent`, but then return data is parent data in `inner_hits`, how can I query by parent and structure data is like `has_child`?

---

**Request body:**

```
{
"query": {
    "has_parent": {
        "parent_type": "order",
        "query": {
            "bool":{
                "should": [
                    {
                        "regexp": { "order_id": ".*100000156.*"}
                    },
                    {
                        "regexp": { "pro_id": ".*70LTJ315.*"}
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "inner_hits": {"size": 10}
    }
},
```

I want parent data in the `hits._source`, child data in the `inner_hits` and simultaneously query by parent field. I don't know how to do the same.

Comment: i want parent data in the "hits._source", child data in the "inner_hits" , simultaneously ， query by parent field , i do not know how to do

Comment: May you please add a couple of example documents and the desired output?